# Use struct and recursion to find the largest number in an integer array

Tags: c++, recursion, struct

I'm required to use recursion to find the largest number in an integer array. Also, I need to get both the value and index of the largest number. I used "struct" but it gave me some weird number and I cannot figure out why.

Here's my struct:

```
struct maxNumber
{
    int index;
    int value;
};
```

Here's my find_largest function:

```
maxNumber Numbers::find_largest()
 {
      maxNumber max;

      int current ;//keep track of the current counter

      if(size == 1)
      {
          max.value = numArray[0];
          max.index = 0;
          return max;
      }

      if(current < size && size != 0)  //loop through all numbers in the array
      {
          if(numArray[current] >= max.value)
           {
            max.value = numArray[current];
            max.index = current;
           }

       current++;
       find_largest();
       }


       return max;
 }
```

Then, in the main function, I just did this:

```
int result = num.find_largest().value;
cout << "The largest number is " << result << endl;
```

However, it gives me a very large number. Need some help to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: You don't pass any arguments to `find_largest()`. Won't it just do the same thing over and over until you get a stack overflow? The variables `max` and `current` are local to the method, so they won't remember the values from previous calls.

Comment: 1) Solution should _not_ need a `static`.  2) Divide list in 1/2 per each recursion.  (would say more, by GTG.)

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is that `current` has local storage and thus is reallocated on every call to `findLargest`.  Change the declaration to this

```
static int current = 0;
```

and it should work, if `size` and `numArray` are defined properly elsewhere in the class definition.

But the same thing is happening more subtly with `max`, and it should be declared statically as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just got this fixed. The problem is as what @stvcisco said: I didn't pass the parameters in the function, so it just call the function within itself again and again. 
Here's the fixed code.

```
 maxNumber Numbers::find_largest(maxNumber max, int size)
{
    if(size == 1)
    {
        max.value = numArray[0];
        max.index = 0;
    }

    if( size > 1)  //loop through all numbers in the array
    {
        if(numArray[size-1] >= max.value)
        {
            max.value = numArray[size-1];
            max.index = size-1;
            return max = find_largest(max, size-1);
        }
        //return max = find_largest(max, size-1);

        else
        {
            size--;
            find_largest(max,size);
        }

    }


    return max;
}
```